# NHibernate saving of related entities

Tags: c#, nhibernate, one-to-one

I have a basic structure. A User object and a UserDetails object. The User table has the identity primary key to generate the UserId, and then I want to also save a UserDetails object for this UserId. Doing this separately this would be easy, but I'm trying to find a way if I can do it in one go, as the User class contains a reference to the UserDetails object. eg

User u = new User() { Name="me", Age=17, UserDetails = new UserDetails() { Detail1 = 1 } };

So all I have to do is pass around the user object, which then contains object based references to other related sub-information (I have simplified it greatly for this example but there are several more similar classes as UserDetails, like UserMatchConfiguration etc and a lot of fields for each one)

I want to be able to build up the object in code, or to have it passed around and modified, then to call save on the parent User object, and for it to then save all related objects. I have achieved this so far using one-to-one mappings and save cascades, but the problem is when you create a new object, the UserId is set to zero for all related classes when I want it to save the User class first, then to propogate the generated UserId to all the related classes and then save them.

Mapping is as follows so far.

```
<class name="User" table="[User]">
    <id name="UserId" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" />
    <property name="LastName" />
    <property name="EmailAddress" />
    <property name="DateOfBirth" />
    <property name="Gender" />
    <property name="PostcodePartOne" />
    <property name="PostcodePartTwo" />
    <many-to-one name="UserLocation" column="UserLocationId" />
    <property name="DateJoined" />
    <property name="LastLoggedOn" />
    <property name="Status"/>
    <property name="StatusNotes" />
    <bag name="Photos" order-by="DisplayOrder asc" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="UserId" />
      <one-to-many class="UserPhoto" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Interests" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="UserId" />
      <one-to-many class="UserMatchInterest" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Preferences" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="all">
      <key column="UserId" />
      <one-to-many class="UserPreference" />
    </bag>
    <one-to-one name="Profile" class="UserProfile" cascade="save-update" />
    <one-to-one name="MatchCriteria" class="UserMatchCriteria" />
    <one-to-one name="MatchLifestyle" class="UserMatchLifestyle" />
    <property name="LastUpdated" />
  </class>
```

As you can see I am trialing it just with the Profile object for now to try and get it working. How can I have it so that the main User object saves first, then passes the UserId to the other classes as they all use that as their primary key?

Again I could not do the cascade save, then set the UserId manually on each sub class and save them separately, but I am trying to do it in a single call.

Comment: What does it mean that you 'propogate the generated UserId'? NH is handling associations for you - why would you want to manage id wiring by yourself? Just make an object graph and call session.save() on parent entity (remember to setup save cascades).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you are almost there. your `user` class mapping seems correct, so the suspected for me is `UserProfile`.

NHibernate supports exactly this style of relations and it is the `one-to-one` mapping (as you've tried). While we cannot see the *UserProfile* mapping, let's extend it following the documentation:

- http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone (docs)
- http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one (more exciting reading)

`UserProfile` hbm

```
<class name="UserProfile" table="[UserProfile]">
  <id name="UserProfileId" column="UserId">
    <generator class="foreign">
      <param name="property">User</param>
    </generator>
  </id>
  ...
  <one-to-one name="User" class="User" constrained="true"/>
</class>
```

The UserProfile need these properties:

```
public class UserProfile 
{
   public virtual int UserProfileId { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Before insert we have to connect both ends (this is very important step):

```
user.Profile =  profile;
profile.User = user;
```

and if the cascade mapping in the `user.hbm.xml` will look like this:

```
 <one-to-one name="Profile" class="UserProfile" cascade="all" />
```

we can save just a **`user`** and all other entities will be (in correct orther) persisted by NHiberante. No need to handle ID anyhow.

Comment: Perfect, the foreign generator bit and linkback property to the parent object is exactly what I needed. Also, what would I need to do to achieve the same with a bag collection? Eg I have a class UserPhoto and the UserObject has a bag of UserPhoto objects that I want it to save in the same single Save statement, each photo has a photoid unique identifier, but the second column is UserId which is a FK constraint into user. Can I get it so the single user.Save creates each row in the UserPhoto table and populates the UserId column?

Comment: Yes, NHibernate will cover this as well. Bag in this case should be marked as inverse, to avoid insert and then update. So if you will allow cascade, this will work for you anyway... http://ayende.com/blog/4043/nhibernate-mapping-list

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that link out now. One last quick one, with the first scenario we discussed, if it is an update (assume this is using nhibernate merge function?) is there a way to just update the UserProfile part of it if I have set it up with the cascade saves? Say if I know the userprofile object is the only one that has changed and I want to avoid saving the entire structure. As now I am calling save on the parent user, does this mean I have to update the entire structure each time? Thanks for your help, very much appreciated

Comment: Absolutely! The only issue is during the insert (as you described int he qeustion) later.. SELECT, UPDATE... `UserProfile` will act as usuall entity. It can be queried, changed... anything;)

Comment: So I can just do repository.SaveItem(user.UserProfile)? even though it is configured as a cascade save from user, I can still do that in isolation if required? Will I need an unsaved-value attribute on the ID tag of the UserProfile hbm.xml then?

Comment: It seems when I learn how to do it all it is very powerful, it's just knowing the tricks! So obviously when updating I don't need the unsaved-value attribute. Is an update in NHibernate done with the Merge function?

Comment: Please, stop discussion here. You are on the right way. If will experience anything else what cannot be found in documentation or is not already answered here on stackoverflow - rise a new question. Enjoy NHibernate ;)